# MySql OUTFILE is not working in rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In one of my rails action i want to create a csv file from a table using MySql OUTFILE.

```
path = "#{Rails.root}/public/outfile.csv"
query_string = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '#{path}' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' FROM temp_csv_186;"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_string)
```

But every time its showing the error.

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't create/write to file '/home/user/Projects/Application/public/outfile.csv' (Errcode: 13): SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/user/Projects/Application/public/outfile.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' FROM temp_csv_186;
```

Answer (score 0):

Has whichever user Mysql runs under got write permissions for /home/user/Projects/Application/public/ ?

Comment: Have you given the MySQL user FILE perms (CREATE USER MyDBconnecter...with FILE perms) and/or made sure they are able to create the files separately from Rails?

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh I think you can't create a file in public, you should give the file location/name as "/tmp/filename.csv"